# Functional recursion satisfying $a_{n+1} = p(a_n)$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients such that $p(0) = p(1) = 1$. We define the sequence $a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ that starts with an arbitrary integer $a_0$ and satisfies $a_{n+1} = p(a_n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that the numbers $a_i$, taken two at a time, are relatively prime.

Since $p(0) = p(1) = 1$, we have $p(x) = x(x-1)g(x)+1$ where $g(x)$ is a nonzero polynomial with integer coefficients. How do we continue from here?

Comment: if $\gcd(a_i,a_{i+1})=d$ then $d | 1$.

Comment: @rtybase The question is asking for pairwise relatively prime, not just for adjacent terms.

Comment: Then for any $a_i$ and $a_j$ such that $i<j$ we have $a_j=p(p(...p(a_i)...))$ and $a_i$ will be all over the places except the last coefficients which sum up to 1 due to p(1) = 1. Let me compile this into an answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f,g$ are two polynomials, then $f(g(x))= x h(x) + f(g(0))$.

In particular, $p(p(x))=x h(x)+p(p(0))=x h(x) + 1$. By induction, $p^n(x)=xh_n(x)+1$.

Then $a_{k+n}=p^n(a_k)=a_k h_n(a_k)+1$ and so $a_{k+n}$ and $a_k$ are coprime.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume $p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_kx^k$ and from $p(0)=a_0=1$ and $p(1)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k=1$. Now $$p(p(x))=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_kp(x)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \left( \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_ix^i \right)^k=$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \left(1+ \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ix^i \right)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \left(1+ xg(x)\right)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \left(1+xG_k(x)\right)=$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \left(a_k+a_kxG_k(x)\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k+x\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_kG_k(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k + xT_1(x)=1 + xT_1(x)$$

Now $p(p(p(x)))=p(1 + xT_1(x))=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \left(1 + xT_1(x)\right)^k=1 + xT_2(x)$ similarly and so on by induction.

Then for any $a_i$ and $a_j$ such that $i<j$ we have $a_j=p(p(...p(a_i)...))=1+a_iT_{j-i}(a_i)$

Comment: What is $T(x)$?

Comment: Just another polynomial ... still typing